# C# inherit properties from a field

Tags: c#

A useful feature of C# is `using static <ClassName>` to for example use `Math` functions without prefixing them with `Math.Function`, but just `Function`. Is something similar possible as a shorthand for `myField.anotherField` as just `anotherField`?

This is of course possible by just `AnotherField /*actually a property now*/ { get => myField.anotherField; set => myField.anotherField = value; }` ( which adds maintenance cost ), or just extending a class.

My use case for this is that an abstract class `State` knows of an `Entity` that it is attached to ( it can't and shouldn't extend `Entity` ). The classes that extend `State` use the readonly entity field to communicate with the entity, but they act as the entity itself so I think it would be handy not to have to write "entity" each time I want to access its fields. Is this at all possible or do I have to just maintain a bunch of properties that redirect to the correct fields?

Comment: If the entity is an object of a class, this is the way to access its properties. So is it an object, or a static class, named Entity?

Comment: You can facade it, with a method, maybe even extension method, but this pattern is not very common.

Comment: As i know there is no common way to do it in c#, but in vb.net u can use `With` => https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/with-end-with-statement

Comment: How do properties add maintenance cost compared to fields? Yes, `public T P {get; set;}` has a few more characters than `public T P;`, but in some ways it allows for more flexibility during maintenance (without changing the class's interface) than a field would.

Comment: @Flydog57 i want an automatic way to reference a field of a field the same way as `using static` does ( see CorrM's answer ), not add these properties myslef.

Comment: Since you are using composition over inheritance, you can not access the properties of the member object without first referring to the member object. What you wish to do is surely possible if you are using inheritance. `Math` is a static class. So you never have to create an object of it to call it's methods. But that's not the case with non-static classes. So what you are asking is only possible by using wrapper properties.